# Why php threads are sequential not parallel on my localhost?

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I want to use `pthread` in `php` to do some tasks in parallel. I have installed `pthread` on `xampp` on `win10` and I just copied some examples from websites but the result of all of them is sequential instead of parallel!
One example from http://www.smddzcy.com/2016/01/tutorial-multi-threading-in-php7-pthreads/:

```
<?php

class SomeThreadedClass extends Thread
{
    private $tID;
    public $data;

    public function __construct(int $tID)
    {
        $this->tID = $tID;
        $this->data = $tID . ":" . date('H:i:s');
    }

    public function run()
    {
        echo $this->tID . " started.\n";
        sleep($this->tID);
        echo $this->tID . " ended. " . date('H:i:s') . "\n";
    }
}

$threads = [];

for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $threads[$i] = new SomeThreadedClass($i);
    $threads[$i]->start();          // start the job on the background
}

for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $threads[$i]->join();           // wait until job is finished, 
    echo $threads[$i]->data . "\n"; // then we can access the data
}
```

The result on the website is:

```
1 started.
 2 started.
 3 started.
 4 started.
 1 ended. 18:18:52
 1:18:18:51
 2 ended. 18:18:53
 2:18:18:51
 3 ended. 18:18:54
 3:18:18:51
 4 ended. 18:18:55
 4:18:18:51
```

When I run the code on my localhost, I get this result:

```
1 started. 
1 ended. 13:11:24 
2 started. 
2 ended. 13:11:25 
3 started. 3 ended. 13:11:26 
4 started. 4 ended. 13:11:27 
1:15:41:23 
2:15:41:23 
3:15:41:23 
4:15:41:23
```

Why threads are sequential not parallel on my localhost?

Comment: maybe the extension doesnt work very well on windows looks like the tutorial was based on a MaC pc.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I checked many other examples from the other websites and all of them had a serial result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The threads *are* executing in parallel. You can tell that by looking at the times being output. All threads start at the same time, and they each finish just 1 second between each joined thread. Given that the `sleep` time is being incremented on each new thread being spawned, the time gap between each thread finishing would incrementally increase if they executed sequentially.

For example, changing the thread spawning and joining part of your script to the following (to force sequential execution):

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $threads[$i] = new SomeThreadedClass($i);
    $threads[$i]->start();          // start the job on the background
    $threads[$i]->join();           // wait until job is finished, 
    echo $threads[$i]->data . "\n"; // then we can access the data
}
```

Would output something similar to:

```
1 started.
1 ended. 15:14:06
1:15:14:05
2 started.
2 ended. 15:14:08
2:15:14:06
3 started.
3 ended. 15:14:11
3:15:14:08
4 started.
4 ended. 15:14:15
4:15:14:11
```

Notice the different start times and the incremental gaps between the finish times.

As for why you are receiving the output in that sequence, it is simply how the output buffer is handling the output from multiple threads. My output is different, but then I'm using OS X.